# Scikit-learn - What am I predicting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

My aim is to predict between five and six numbers in an array, based on csv data with six columns. The below script is supposed to predict only one number, from an array of 5. I assumed I could work my way up to the entire 5 or 6 from there, but I might be wrong about that.

Mre:

```
import csv
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv('subdata.csv')

ft = [9,8,15,4,6]

fintest = np.array(ft)

def train():

    df.astype(np.float64)
    df.drop(['One'], axis = 1)
    X = df
    y = X['One']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=123)

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

    tree_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
    rf_model = RandomForestRegressor()

    tree_model.fit(train_scaled, y_train)
    rf_model.fit(train_scaled, y_train)

    rfp = rf_model.predict(fintest.reshape(1, -1))
    tmp = tree_model.predict(fintest.reshape(1, -1))

    print(rfp)
    print(tmp)

train()
```

**Could you please clarify, what I am asking this script to predict in the final `rfp` and `tmp` lines?**

My data looks like this:

[image: subdata.csv image]

The script as is currently gives an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\conra\Desktop\Code\lotto\pie.py", line 43, in <module>
    train()
  File "C:\Users\conra\Desktop\Code\lotto\pie.py", line 37, in train
    rfp = rf_model.predict(fintest.reshape(1, -1))
  File "C:\Users\conra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py", line 784, in predict
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\conra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py", line 422, in _validate_X_predict
    return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
  File "C:\Users\conra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py", line 402, in _validate_X_predict
    X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr",
  File "C:\Users\conra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 437, in _validate_data
    self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
  File "C:\Users\conra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 365, in _check_n_features
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: X has 5 features, but DecisionTreeRegressor is expecting 6 features as input.
```

By adding a sixth digit to the `ft` array I can get around this error and receive wildly inaccurate outputs, that appear to have no correlation with the data whatsoever. For example, by setting variable `ft` to `[9,8,15,4,6,2]` which is the first row in the csv file, and setting X and y to use the 'Four' label; I get an output of `[37.22]` and `[37.]`.

My other questions will probably be answered by my first. But here they are:

**Could you also please clarify why I need to pass an array of 6?**

**And why are my predictions so close together (all ~35), no matter what array I pass for the prediction?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The way you defined your X is wrong. It is containing 6 features.**

Your y is contained in your X in the way you defined it :

```
X = df #6 features
y = X['One'] #1 feature
```

I think what you wanted to do was something like this :

```
X = df[['Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Zero']]
y = df['One']
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data, and like I saw your data is an example without context, so actually you are trying to train your data to predict the 'One' column using two different **models**, that doesn't make sense to me.

The error is because you give to `X` the dataframe without column 'One' and after you are asking for the column 'One' to variable `Y`, `Y=X['One']`.